# Hibernate instrumentation leads to verification errors?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, instrumentation

I'm trying to apply lazy-loading of basic fields (String with huge xml) with Hibernate 3.5.x on MySQL. It seems this does only work for Postgresql. At least not for MySQL.

What should work is to instrument the entities byte code with Hibernate's "instrumenttask". The instrumentation seems to run ok. Using [this Maven example](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Howto+instrument+domain+model+classes+using+hibernate). But now the byte code verifier complains about invalid methods.

No panic. It seems this can happen when running with different versions of cglib and asm in the classpath. And indeed, the final war files do contain for than version. I've replaced them with cglib-nodep 2.2 and asm-all 3.x.

Alas... still getting the same error from the verifier.

It's probably a classic mistake I'm making, but I can't find what's wrong really.

Somebody in here already could make this work ?

Thanks !

Jan